# XAMP Refuses to Start Apache on Mac os 10.8

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, osx-lion

I have been trying to fix a composer error which didn't allow me to download due to ssl not being enabled and I simply removed the ";" from the php.ini file and restarted my computer.

However I now get an error

"XAMPP's Apache can not start while Web Sharing is on! Please go to System Preferences > Sharing and turn it off."

when trying to start apache... however I do not even have a setting for "Web Sharing" in my System Preferences. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

open Terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: Could you provide explanation why this should help? It didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you provide explanation why this should help? It did work for me.